# qtip2 modal mode not working in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, qtip2

I'm using qtip2 every thing is good but modal tip is not working in IE7:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[rel="master-modal-tip"]').each(function () {
        $(this).qtip(
        {
            content: { text: $('#' + $(this).attr('ttid')), title: { text: '', button: true} },
            position: { my: 'center', at: 'center', target: $(window) },
            show: { event: 'click', modal: { on: true, blur: false} },
            hide: false,
            style: { classes: 'master-modal-tip' }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Also i am copy this code, but it is not working for me: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My JQuery version was 1.4 and i updated to last version (1.8.3), and modal issue now working fine in IE7.